# Why doesn't map read from @ARGV/@_?

Tags: perl

Is there a good reason for [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to not read from `@_` (in functions) or `@ARGV` (anywhere else) when not given an argument list?

Comment: Why would `map` do that when no other built-in does, except array operators?

Comment: It's not an unreasonable expectation. If `shift` does this, why not `map`?

Comment: `map` doesn't take an array. Fixed.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst If `shift` does it, why not `print`? Why not `join`? Why not `reverse, splice, grep`? Why would `map` be special?

Comment: To be fair, `print` and `reverse` will use `$_`.

Comment: @TLP, I'm sure you'll find he'll say "why not indeed?"

Comment: @ikegami ...while stroking his chin and raising an eyebrow?  He will, I've seen him do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't say why Larry didn't make `map`, `grep` and the other list functions operate on `@_` like `pop` and `shift` do, but I can tell you why I wouldn't.  Default variables used to be in vogue, but Perl programmers have discovered that most of the "default" behaviors cause more problems than they solve.  I doubt they would make it into the language today.

The first problem is remembering what a function does when passed no arguments.  Does it act on a hidden variable?  Which one?  You just have to know by rote, and that makes it a lot more work to learn, read and write the language.  You're probably going to get it wrong and that means bugs.  This could be mitigated by Perl being consistent about it (ie. ALL functions which take lists operate on @_ and ALL functions which take scalars operate on $_) but there's more problems.

The second problem is the behavior changes based on context.  Take some code outside of a subroutine, or put it into a subroutine, and suddenly it works differently.  That makes refactoring harder.  If you made it work on *just* `@_` or *just* `@ARGV` then this problem goes away.

Third is default variables have a tendency to be quietly modified as well as read.  `$_` is dangerous for this reason, you never know when something is going to overwrite it.  If the use of `@_` as the default list variable were adopted, this behavior would likely leak in.

Fourth, it would probably lead to complicated syntax problems.  I'd imagine this was one of the original reasons keeping it from being added to the language, back when `$_` was in vogue.

Fifth, `@ARGV` as a default makes some sense when you're writing scripts that primarily work with `@ARGV`... but it doesn't make any sense when working on a library.  Perl programmers have shifted from writing quick scripts to writing libraries.

Sixth, using `$_` as default is a way of chaining together scalar operations without having to write the variable over and over again.  This might have been mitigated if Perl was more consistent about its return values, and if regexes didn't have special syntax, but there you have it.  Lists can already be chained, `map { ... } sort { ... } grep /.../, @foo`, so that use case is handled by a more efficient mechanism.

Finally, it's of very limited use.  It's very rare that you want to pass `@_` to `map` and `grep`.  The problems with hidden defaults are far greater than avoiding typing two characters.  This space savings might have *slightly* more sense when Perl was primarily for quick and dirty work, but it makes no sense when writing anything beyond a few pages of code.

PS  `shift` defaulting to `@_` has found a niche in `my $self = shift`, but I find this only shines because Perl's argument handling is so poor.

Comment: Sadly, the reason I want it in the first place is to make `perl -E 'say map{pack B8,$_}@ARGV'` shorter, so I don't really have a good reason for it in the first place.

Comment: @Chas.Owens Write a script, stick it in `~/bin`.

Comment: The functionality isn't the point. I am trying to cheat at golf.

Answer (score 2):

The `map` function takes in a list, not an array. `shift` takes an array. With lists, on the other hand, `@_`/`@ARGV` may or may not be fair defaults.

Comment: While this is *technically* correct (the best kind of correct), I don't the connection.  Why does it mean `map` can't use `@_` as a default?  `map` can take an array just fine.

Comment: I guess what I'm really trying to say is, `@_`/`@ARGV` (being arrays) are sensible defaults for array functions, but when you expand it to lists, you might want to consider more than that. For example, why not have the default argument be `($_)`, in other words the single-element list containing `$_`? Then `map` would basically just transform `$_`. I'm not saying that would be a realistic implementation decision (especially since you can just invoke the corresponding operations on `$_` directly), but I think it has about the same appeal from a purely theoretical perspective.

Comment: Actually, if you think about it, you could say that `print` DOES operate on `($_)`. That's incorrect, but semantically identical to what it does do. `reverse` might do the same, but it is special-cased to reverse the scalar as a string if passed one argument so that muddies the waters a bit.

Comment: This is the answer I would have given if it hadn't already been answered, although I would have added that everyone should get over "why". It's a stupid question for a hodgepodge language like Perl. "Why" is always "because Larry did it that way". Small, orthogonal languages want to preserve a central idea and maintain consistency. Perl is not one of those languages.

Comment: @briandfoy I *strongly* disagree.  If you don't ask *why* we did things, or didn't do them, or wouldn't do them today, then you *continue* to be a hodgepodge language.  Just because Perl isn't Lisp doesn't mean we don't need to understand the reasons for what we do.  Single-idea language or not, you still have to rationally design.

Comment: You can disagree, but we continue to have a hodgepodge language today. It's not _asking_ why that's the problem. It's expecting a consistent answer to the question. As far as "rationally" design, that depends on what you assume is rational. Perl clearly has a different idea of that than many other languages.